# Accessing double pointer from another class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'd like to access to a double pointer which is located in another class "Board".

```
class Board
{
public:
    Board(void);
    Board(unsigned int xSize, unsigned int ySize);
    ~Board(void);

    void SetObjectManager(ObjectManager* pObm);
    void SetBlock(Block* block);

    void LoadBoard(void);
    void InitBoard(void);
   //Other Functions...

private:
    ObjectManager* m_obm;
    Block* m_block;

    //pointer to pointer to a int. (for 2 dimensional-array)
    int **m_board;
};
```

First, the Board class. at the last line of class, you can see m_board.
I want to change this value in outside of this class.

Like this,

```
void Block::InitBlock(void)
{   
    int randPiece = Random::GIRand().RandInt(0, 1);
    int randPos   = Random::GIRand().RandInt(0, 10);

    switch (randPiece)
    {
    case 0:
        m_piece[2][1] = 1;
        m_piece[2][2] = 1;
        m_piece[2][3] = 1;
        m_piece[3][3] = 1;
        break;
    //Other cases are here...
    }

    std::cout << "RandPos : " << randPos << std::endl;
    std::cout << "RandPiece : " << randPiece << std::endl;

    for (int y = 0; y < m_ySize; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0, pX = randPos; x < m_xSize; ++x, ++randPos)
        {
            if (m_piece[x][y] != 0)
                m_board->SetBoardStatus(randPos, y, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

But, When I run this program, It blows up at SetBoardStatus(int, int, int)

SetBoardStatus looks like this,

```
void Board::SetBoardStatus(int x, int y, int value)
{
    m_board[x][y] = value; //Visual Studio breaks the program here.
}
```

I allocate the double pointer properly. 
And I set the board at the outside of this classes.

```
void Block::SetBoard(Board* board)
{
    m_board = board;
}
```

And this is my block class.

```
class Block
{
public:
    Block(void);
    ~Block(void);

    void SetObjectManager(ObjectManager* pObm);

    void LoadBlock     (void);
    void InitBlock     (void);
    void UpdateBlock   (void);
    void ReleaseBlock  (void);

    void SetBoard(Board* board);

private:
    ObjectManager* m_obm;
    Board* m_board;

    int **m_piece;

    int m_xSize;
    int m_ySize;

};
```

Comment: I can't spot any memory allocations in your code.

Comment: Aside from the fact that the Board class declaration does not actually have a SetBoardStatus() class member, I see nothing wrong with the code. Please edit your question, remove all the code you've included in it, and replace the code with a [mcve].

Comment: Too much code. Probably needs to be reduced to an example which the double pointer is the only member variable.

Comment: _@Woong_ Your sample code shown here is completely useless to diagnose the problem. The best advice I can give is: Check the values of `x` and `y`when `m_board[x][y] = value;` is executed and be sure the pointers point to actually allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

Consider inheriting Block in Board; This will eliminate any possible de-referencing errors or bugs, as you can access the pointer right away.